# Fitting piecewise function: running into NaN problems due to boolean array indexing

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, ipython

So I've been trying to fit to an exponentially modified gaussian function (if interested, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentially_modified_Gaussian_distribution)

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as sio
import scipy.special as sps

def exp_gaussian(x, h, u, c, t):
    z = 1.0/sqrt(2.0) * (c/t - (x-u)/c)   #not important
    k1 = k2 = h * c / t * sqrt(pi / 2)    #not important
    n1 = 1/2 * (c / t)**2 - (x-u)/t       #not important
    n2 = -1 / 2 * ((x - u) / c)**2        #not important
    y = np.zeros(len(x))
    y += (k1 * np.exp(n1) * sps.erfc(z)) * (z < 0)
    y += (k2 * np.exp(n2) * sps.erfcx(z)) * (z >= 0)
    return y
```

In order to prevent overflow problems, one of two equivilent functions must be used depending on whether z is positive or negative (see Alternative forms for computation from previous wikipedia page).

**The problem I am having is this:** The line `y += (k2 * np.exp(n2) * sps.erfcx(z)) * (z >= 0)`is only supposed to add to y when z is positive. But if z is, say, -30, `sps.erfcx(-30)` is `inf`, and inf * False is NaN. Therefore, instead of leaving y untouched, the resulting y is clustered with NaN. Example:

```
x = np.linspace(400, 1000, 1001)
y = exp_gaussian(x, 100, 400, 10, 5)
y
array([ 84.27384586,  86.04516723,  87.57518493, ...,          nan,
                nan,          nan])
```

I tried the replacing the line in question with the following:

```
y += numpy.nan_to_num((k2 * np.exp(n2) * sps.erfcx(z)) * (z >= 0))
```

But doing this ran into serious runtime issues. Is there a way to only evaluate `(k2 * np.exp(n2) * sps.erfcx(z))` on the condition that `(z >= 0)` ? Is there some other way to solve this without sacrificing runtime?

Thanks!

EDIT: After Rishi's advice, the following code seems to work much better:

```
def exp_gaussian(x, h, u, c, t):
    z = 1.0/sqrt(2.0) * (c/t - (x-u)/c)
    k1 = k2 = h * c / t * sqrt(pi / 2)
    n1 = 1/2 * (c / t)**2 - (x-u)/t
    n2 = -1 / 2 * ((x - u) / c)**2
    return = np.where(z >= 0, k2 * np.exp(n2) * sps.erfcx(z), k1 * np.exp(n1) * sps.erfc(z))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using [numpy.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with something like: `np.where(z >= 0, sps.erfcx(z), sps.erfc(z))`.  I'm no numpy expert, so don't know if it's efficient.  Looks elegant at least!

Comment: This seemed to work quite well. The only problem is that when I run np.where(z >= 0, sps.erfcx(z), sps.erfc(z)), I get runtime warnings because it still evaluates sps.erfcx(z) and sps.erfc(z). Is there an easy way to avoid evaluating the incorrect parameter?

Comment: Glad to know it worked. Just curious: how did you get runtime warnings? Because, yes, the logical thing to expect would be that it would evaluate both erfcx and erfc on the entire z, but then np.where would select between those two evaluations based on the sign of z element-by-element. And thus, the NaNs in erfcx would be discarded.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is create a mask and reuse it so it wouldn't need to be evaluated twice. Another idea is to use the nan_to_num only once at the end

```
mask = (z<0)
y += (k1 * np.exp(n1) * sps.erfc(z)) * (mask)
y += (k2 * np.exp(n2) * sps.erfcx(z)) * (~mask)
y = numpy.nan_yo_num(y)
```

Try and see if this helps...